# C# Extension Method not working for increment and decrement scenarios, is it by design?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am trying a simple Extension Method example and am unable to increment or decrement an int.
Here is the code

```
static class ExtensionMethodsExp
{
    public static void Print(this object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is print: {0}", o.ToString());
    }

    public static int Double(this int i)
    {
        return i * 2;
    }
    public static int Decrement(this int i)
    {
         return i--;
    }

    public static int Increment(this int i)
    {
        return i++;

    }
}
```

}

Program Code is

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       int myNumber = 10;
       myNumber.Print();

       myNumber = myNumber.Double();
       myNumber.Print();

       myNumber = myNumber.Decrement(); 
       myNumber.Print();

       myNumber = myNumber.Increment();
       myNumber.Print();

       myNumber.Increment().Double().Print();
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I am getting following as output

This is print: 10

This is print: 20

This is print: 20

This is print: 20

This is print: 40

Any idea why Decrement or Increment should not work here. Is there something I am missing?
thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you would even want to use myNumber = myNumber.Increment() instead of myNumber+1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int Decrement(this int i)
{
     return --i;
}

public static int Increment(this int i)
{
    return ++i;
}
```

Comment: I think i+1 and i-1 would be clearer - there is no need to increment the input value, since it isn't used again.

Comment: @MvsW: i-- and i++ do not work because it is the post-increment/decrement oprator so order is "first take value then increment/decrement it" while --i/++i is "first increment/decrement value then take it". But i+1/i-1 would be much cleaner because eith i--/i++ you change the value stored in i but do not use it instead of returning it.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your code is not working is because of the way you are using the Increment and Decrement operators.

When you write:

```
return i++;
```

The value of i is returned BEFORE the increment occurs.

Try this:

```
return ++i;
```

or better yet, this:

```
return i + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a matter of reference, since you are assigning the return value back to the value.

The issue here is that `i++` increments *after* it is used. In this case, it is being returned, and then incremented. Since the variable is a value type, it's only the local variable inside Increment() that is being incremented.

If you use `++i` then the local member is incremented and *then* returned, which is more what you were expecting.

Having said that, it is confusing to name your method Increment or Decrement since it does not automatically assign the value back to the original. <strike>Have you tried passing in `ref this i`? I have no idea if ref can be used in this situation, but it may make the method naming more accurate.</strike> [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has thwarted this idea.

Comment: You can't make an extension method on a ref. What would it look like at the call site?  (ref x).Foo(y) ? That would be goofy, so we don't allow it.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking more from the compiled form, since it's a static call.

Answer (score 0):

This is because i++ doesn't increment the number until *after* the function has been completely evaluated.  Unfortunately, in your example, you return the original value and the incremented value is lost on the stack!

++i increments i *before* the function evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

`++i` means:

- Increment the value of i
- Return the incremented value

`i++` means:

- Remember the current value of i
- Increment the value of i
- Remember the previous value of i (i.e. from before you incremented it)

The one is called the "preincrement" operator, and the other is called the "postincrement" operator.